# When to prefer the biased estimate of variance over the unbiased estimate

Tags: numpy, statistics

I just found out today that numpy's variance function defaults to returning the biased variance estimate (i.e. dividing by N instead of N-1). I have two questions.

1. If one is working with a sample is there ever a good reason to prefer the biased estimate? I understand that the unbiased estimator converges to the infinite population's variance as n increases and why. Are there practical reasons for ever preferring the biased estimate?
2. Why does numpy default to this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The correct divisor to use depends on what you are doing.  For example:

- If you know the mean of the distribution exactly and use that exact mean when calculating variance, then the correct divisor is N.
- If you estimate *one* parameter from the sample, say the mean, then the correct (unbiased) divisor to use is `N-1`.
- If you estimate *two* parameters, say intercept and slope, and  compute the variance using these two estimates, then the correct (unbiased) divisor to use is `N-2`.

Some background information on this can be found [here](http://arnoldkling.com/apstats/df.html) and [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/df.html).